# How to add a specific character to a set of characters in a NSString

Tags: objective-c, nsstring, nsregularexpression

I want to add a specific character in front of a set of characters in a NSString.

For example:

```
NSString *input = @"abc^ 123 # //> <";    
NSString *insertBefore = @"~";
NSCharacterSet *needBeInserted = [NSCharacterSet 
                        characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"~#^/<>"];
```

Expected result: any characters in `needBeInserted` that appears in `input` will add `insertBefore`.

```
result = @"abc~^ 123 ~# ~/~/~> ~<";
```

Is there an elegant way to do it? Instead of use multiple lines of `stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString`?

Comment: Use [`escapedPattern`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsregularexpression/1408386-escapedpatternforstring?language=objc)

Comment: Unfortunately, some characters like: `<` , `>` are not included.

Comment: But they are not special inside a regex, they do not have to be escaped. Please define your exact requirements (which chars do you need to escape?) in the question.

Comment: That's why I create a `NSCharacterSet` to store the characters that need to be escaped in my case. On quick solution is to go through `NSCharacterSet` and call `stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString` for each character in the set. Just want to know if there's a better solution :)

Comment: Please add exact reqs to the question.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Additionally `-escapePattern` creates a regex escaped string, not a C escaped string as in his example.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew updated. Hopefully it can be more clearto you.

Comment: Note that a regex solution is to use a `[~#^/<>]` pattern and replace with `~$0`. See [this online demo](https://ideone.com/d48SZu).

Comment: So, you do not need a `NSCharacterSet`, just define the character class with the chars you need. Well, you can define "elegant" in various ways.

Comment: Your solution is indeed `elegant`!! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may put your chars into a [**character class**](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) and use a regex based replacement:

```
[~#^/<>]
```

Replace with `~$0` where `$0` inserts the whole match text into the resulting string. See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/wsMkJh/1).

See the [Objective-C demo online](https://ideone.com/d48SZu):

```
NSError *error = nil;
NSString *input = @"abc^ 123 # //> <";
NSString *pat = @"[~#^/<>]";
NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:pat options:nil error:&error];
NSString *modifiedString = [regex stringByReplacingMatchesInString:input 
        options:0 
        range:NSMakeRange(0, [input length]) 
        withTemplate:@"~$0"];
NSLog(@"%@", modifiedString);
```

Result: `abc~^ 123 ~# ~/~/~> ~<`

Answer (score 0):

You have to search the characters and replace it:

```
NSRange searchRange = NSMakeRange( 0,[input length] );
NSRange charRange;
while( (charRange = [input rangeOfCharactersFromSet:escapeSet options:NSBackwardSearch).length range:searchRange)
{
  // It is allowed to have a 0-length range: Insertion
  input = [input stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:NSMakeRange(charRange.location, 0) withString:@"\"];

  // Shorten the search range
  searchRange = NSMakeRange(0, charRange.location);
}
```

Written in Safari. You should test if for edge cases and typos.

Another way is to make an array of (single-letter) strings out of the character set and replace occurrences of it with a combination with the escape character. Seems to be more complex and less natural to me.